# How to build a 2-level dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm slowly getting my feet wet in Python but still seem to miss some fundamentals. Especially with lists and dictionaries.

I'm building an importer and there want to check a directory of files for the ones importable for me. Here's a function I'm trying to build for this:

```
def check_files(directory=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))):
    file_number = 0
    files = {}
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            file_name = os.fsdecode(file)
            --> files = {file_number: {'file_name': file_name}}
            with open(file_name,'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
                line = f.readline()
                if line == firstline['one']:
                    --> files = {file_number: {'file_type': 'one'}}
                elif line == firstline['two']:
                    --> files = {file_number: {'file_type': 'two'}}
                else:
                    --> files = {file_number: {'file_type': 'unknown'}}
        file_number += 1

    return files
```

As you can see I'm failing to build the dictionary I was thinking of building to carry some file information and return it.

Regarding the dictionary structure I was thinking about something like this:

```
files = {
    0: {'file_name': 'test1.csv', 'file_type': 'one'},
    1: {'file_name': 'test2.csv', 'file_type': 'two'}
}
```

My question is: how do I build the dictionary step by step as I get the values and add new dictionaries into it? I read through quite some dictionary explanations for beginners but they mostly don't handle this multi level case at least not building it step by step.

Comment: I gave you a theorical answer, your code with it applied and a suggested alternative that uses a `list` of `dict`s instead of a `dict` of `dict`s as your outter `dict` is using incremental integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the literal construc, you should use the assign operator:

```
base_dict = {} # same that base_dict = dict()

for i in range(10):
    base_dict[i] = {'file_name': 'test' + str(i+1) + '.csv', 'file_type': i+1}
```

The first line is creating an empty `dict`.

The loop iterates i=0..9.
Then we assign a new `dict` to element `i` of `base_dict` with `base_dict[i] = ...`. You use square brackets to both access and modify (including creation) of key-value paris inside a `dict`.

Your code will be:

```
def check_files(directory=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))):
    files = {}
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            i = len(files)
            file_name = os.fsdecode(file)
            files[i] = {'file_name': file_name}
            with open(file_name,'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
                line = f.readline()
                if line == firstline['one']:
                    files[i]['file_type'] = 'one'
                elif line == firstline['two']:
                    files[i]['file_type'] = 'one'
                else:
                    files[i]['file_type'] = 'unknown'
    return files
```

As you can see I deleted the manual count you were using and get the number of already existing elements with `i = len(files)`, then I use square brackets to enter all the info as needed.

#### IMPORTANT NOTE

Your case may be more complex than this, but having a dictionary whos keys are auto-incremented integers makes no sense, that is what `list`s are for. Your code with lists would look like this:

```
def check_files(directory=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))):
    files = []
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            file_name = os.fsdecode(file)
            files.append({'file_name': file_name})
            with open(file_name,'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
                line = f.readline()
                if line == firstline['one']:
                    files[-1]['file_type'] = 'one'
                elif line == firstline['two']:
                    files[-1]['file_type'] = 'one'
                else:
                    files[-1]['file_type'] = 'unknown'
    return files
```

As you can see it is very similar to the code above but it doesn't need to calculate the length every iteration as the builtin method `list.append()` already inserts the new data in the next position. `list`s offer you some advantages over `dict`s in the case of auto-incremented integers as keys.

The output would be:

files = [
    {'file_name': 'test1.csv', 'file_type': 'one'},
    {'file_name': 'test2.csv', 'file_type': 'two'}
]

Remember that even the output doesn't explicitly writes the numbers, `list`s allow you to access the data the same way. Additionally, negative integers can be used to access data from the bottom, so when I'm using `files[-1]`, that means the last element we inserted. That's the reason why I do not need to know which element we are introducing in this example, we just append it at the end and access the last value appended.